# Add deprecation header to all files in subdirectory/path using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have moved some stuff being deprecated to a folder called `legacyFrontend`

I would like to add the [Deprecated header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dalal-deprecation-header-03) to all and any calls to those files using .htaccess

I have tried several things that are just ignored:

```conf
<FilesMatch "^legacyFrontend/.*">
    Header set Deprecation "Sat, 31 Dec 2022 23:59:59 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

```conf
<Files "legacyFrontend/">
    Header set Deprecation "Sat, 31 Dec 2022 23:59:59 GMT"
</Files>
```

This one just returns a 500 error

```conf
<Directory "legacyFrontend">
    Header set Deprecation "Sat, 31 Dec 2022 23:59:59 GMT"
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple:

Put a separate .htaccess file in `/legacyFrontend` with no directives except the Header:

```conf
#deprecation header https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-dalal-deprecation-header-03
Header set Deprecation "Sat, 31 Dec 2022 23:59:59 GMT"
```